# Can anyone tell me the names of known uniswap v2 forks?

Tags: uniswap, defi

im compiling a list and i need to know the names of as many uniswap v2 forks.
Only ones that exist on the ethereum mainnet.
i know of sushiswap, sakeswap and defiswap

Comment: I also know of Kingswap

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to tell, because there is a new swap service almost every day.

You might want to limit your query with some criteria, like volume, etc. and then use services like [DefiPulse](https://defipulse.com) to figure it out by yourself.

Comment: i need it to use the core structure of uniswap v2

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can get the list of uniswap forks at https://defillama.com/forks/Uniswap

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see the whole list of Exchanges on ETH Mainnet. You will have to sort it out which one is a fork of uniswap. Most them are actually.

https://www.dapp.com/dapps/ethereum-decentralized-exchange?sort=4&time=0&type=0